# Why does SFTP timeout during a download?

Tags: ssh, downloads, sftp

My server keeps timing out when I attempt to download a handful of files at once.

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

`sshd_config` contains the following tweaks:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

Match group www
    ChrootDirectory %h
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

and `fstab` contains the following tweaks:

```
/srv/www/domain.com /home/chris/domain.com none bind
```

After attempting to download the files the user will be disconnected.

I'm not even sure where to begin debugging this, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is the upload over-saturating the server's available upstream bandwidth? It could be knocking out the ssh session.

Comment: Did you try to use different SFTP clients?  (Just to rule out a bug in the one you use...)

Comment: it's happening during downloading. change in clients don't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out it was a misconfiguration with fail to ban, involving both ssh keys and pw checks. for sftp, the key's failed, resulting in a ten minute ban.